# Does weather have any effect on gameplay?

Tags: the-witcher-3

While playing I haven't notice weather making any difference for play in Witcher 3. Yeah, it's there to make the gameplay realistic, but I think maybe there will be some difference in different weather on creatures or Geralt.
Does weather have any measurable effects?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are definitely some effects from weather.

The [Superior Thunderbolt Potion](http://thewitcher3.wiki.fextralife.com/Superior+Thunderbolt) and [Foglet Decotion](http://thewitcher3.wiki.fextralife.com/Foglet+Decoction) are both better in cloudy weather.

If you count time of day as 'weather' then Geralt is affected when he has the [Sun and Stars skill](http://thewitcher3.wiki.fextralife.com/Sun+and+Stars). [Noonwraiths](http://thewitcher3.wiki.fextralife.com/Noonwraith) and [Nightwraiths](http://thewitcher3.wiki.fextralife.com/Nightwraith) are also affected by time of day.

Comment: I wouldn't count "time of day" as "weather", myself. But your point about cloudy weather is quite good, thanks!

Comment: @BryanPendleton I wouldn't really count it as weather either, but chose to include it for completeness